# Overwriting Image to Azure using C# and ReactJS Does Not Refresh the Old Image

Tags: reactjs, azure-blob-storage

I am using reactJS to upload an image and it calls an API endpoint to upload it to Azure Blob Storage using C#. Once uploaded, the page reloads.
When I try to overwrite an existing image, with the same filename, the page reloads but it loads the old image unless I empty cache and hard refresh the page.

Here's what I implemented already.

I am calling clearCacheData to completely delete cached images and files

```
export const clearCacheData = () => {
caches.keys().then((names) => {
    names.forEach((name) => {
        
        caches.delete(name);
    });
});
console.log('Complete Cache Cleared')
```

I call this function before rebinding the image gallery. No luck on doing that.

Comment: Please edit your question and include the code for uploading the blob. My guess is that you are setting `Cache-Control` property of the blob which is causing browsers to cache the image. Also, please explain what `caches` is in your code above.